# How to get a pixel color in a video being played?

Tags: android, mobile

For some specific reasons, I need to get a pixel color in a video being played on my android application. I have to choose a place in the video being played and get this pixel color while the video is playing. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, What have you tried so far to achieve the same?

Comment: @SanthoshJoseph nothing. I couldn't find anything to do this with video, only with images.

Comment: So why not pause the video, take a screenshot (or use the player's capabilities to extract the frame as an image) and process the resulting image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but you can try

- Use [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever) to get a frame for any microsecond.
- then get pixel color from bitmap frame

> ```
>  MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
>
>   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
>
>   Bitmap frame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(10000);
> ```

I dont know how complex it will be. Never tried.

Answer (score -1):

A one time solution if you just want to get pixel for one video only. Use the App https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ochs.pipette&hl=en_US .

**Steps:**

• Take a screenshot.

• Process the Image with this App and find the Code.

**Disclaimer:**
I am not at all associated with this application. I do not get any financial or material support for promoting this App.

Please so not downvote if you didn't mean to get pixel details for a single video. Otherwise Sahdeep Singh's answer is also good.